# How to use the global comparison operator when comparing two different structure types to resolve the errors in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

When I am trying to compare members of two different structures, getting the below errors:

```
error C2676: binary '==': 'main::strRGBSettings' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const T1' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Can someone help how to use the global comparison operator

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 struct strRGBSettings
    {
        uint8_t red;
        uint8_t green;
        uint8_t blue;
    };

    struct strStandardColors
    {
        static strRGBSettings black() { return { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; }
        static strRGBSettings red() { return { 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 }; }
        static strRGBSettings blue() { return { 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF }; }
    };

    struct ColorState
    {
        strRGBSettings     RGB;
    };

    ColorState l_colorState;
    if (l_colorState.RGB == strStandardColors::red())
    {
        std::cout << "The color is of type Red " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler error says, you need to define `operator==` for your `strRGBSettings` struct:

```
struct strRGBSettings {
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    bool operator==(const strRGBSettings& stg) const {
        return stg.red == red && stg.blue == blue && stg.green == green;
    }
};
```

If you cannot modify the struct, define `operator==` as a non-member function:

```
bool operator==(const strRGBSettings& stg1, const strRGBSettings& stg2) const {
    return (stg1.red == stg2.red && stg1.blue == stg2.blue && stg1.green == stg2.green);
}
```

Note that this definition cannot go inside `main`, and you should at least be able to access the struct outside `main`.

Comment: Thank you @Wais Kamal for the solution, The structure strRGBSettings is there in the interface file and i don't have access to it. Can i overload operator== outside of the main function instead of doing it within the sturcture.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Have a look please.